# Knockout.JS 'enable' binding on length condition not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

All the data displaying and adding / deleting buttons seem to work until I change the delete button to do a check to make sure that there is always at least one person on the screen:

```
<!-- Check number of items before enabling delete button  !-->
<button type="button" data-bind='enable: people().length > 1, click: $root.removePerson'>Delete</button>
```

The error is as follows:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return people }"
Message: Unable to process binding "enable: function (){return people().length > 1 }"
Message: people is not defined`

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind='foreach: people'>
    <div class="personWell">  
       <input type="text" data-bind="value: name"></input>
       <input type="text" data-bind="value: company"></input>

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" data-bind='click: $root.removePerson'>Delete</button>
     </div> 
</div>   

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bind='click:addPerson'>Add Person</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ObservedPersonModel = function(people) {

    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray(people);

    self.addPerson = function() {
        self.people.push({
            person_id:"",
            name: "",
            company: "",
            positive_observation_id:""
        });
    };

    self.removePerson = function(person) {
        self.people.remove(person);   
    }; 
};

//originalPeopleObserved is a JSON encoded list of objects
var peopleViewModel = new ObservedPersonModel(originalPeopleObserved);
ko.applyBindings(peopleViewModel);
```

**Resources**

Here are some of the links where I learned about this functionality:

- http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7RDc3/
- http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html

Comment: Since you're inside a `foreach` binding, you need to bind to `$root.people()` instead of just `people()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button type="button" data-bind='enable: $root.people().length > 1, click: $root.removePerson'>Delete</button>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I believe I had tried some variation of that in the process, but not that exact one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got your code running in a fiddle. First thing i changed was two `>` you forgot in your html code:

```
   <input type="text" data-bind="value: name"></input>
   <input type="text" data-bind="value: company"></input>
```

Then i added an empty object for testing:

```
originalPeopleObserved = null;
var peopleViewModel = new ObservedPersonModel(originalPeopleObserved);
ko.applyBindings(peopleViewModel);
```

And on Safari i can use your sample as expected.
Try this [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hexereisoftware/7fq6pg8j/1/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Tyler Smith's solution worked for me.